# After HTTP Keep Alive timeout new HTTP request arrives

Tags: http, https, webserver, keep-alive

Our application is ExtJS 3.4 based application we are frequently getting "**Communication Failure**" error on UI , we have our application deployed on different domain but on some domain we get this very frequently .

**Without HTTP Keep Alive we are not getting that error.** :

But in different scenarios for 1 sec and 5 sec we get it quite frequently.

We have observed on Wireshark was due to high RTT (Round Trip Time) the request were taking more time than expected. 
There were inconsistency in packet flow the scenario was :

If keep alive was 5 sec :

1. When a request is successfully served it will return 200 OK(success response) and timeout parameter of 5 sec (where server tries to say to client that server will wait for 5 sec before closing this connection).
2. Now as soon as 5 sec of time is elapsed Server sends a FIN Packet(Finish packet which is to close connection is sent from server to client which is browser in our case).
3. Now here is the catch the time taken by ACK (Acknowledge Packet) from client to close connection is high ( high RTT).
4. Now server has initiated close but due to high RTT before the connection is closed client sends a new HTTP request(for eg ExampleABC.do request) before server receives ACK for FINISH from client.
5. Because of which server was not able to handle that request since it has initiated connection close.

Setting 1 sec as keep alive meant we are reducing time the server will wait to close the connection since we wanted after 1 sec one connection is to be closed and fresh connection is setup for new request to avoid unwanted request coming after 5 sec .

Thanks in advance 
This is my first post please correct me if needed.
Sorry for bad English :)

**Image for communication failure :**

[image: http://www.bryntum.com/forum/download/file.php?id=3493&sid=5f0c6b2ac3fa0fe9361a23df99644e54]

Comment: Need help from TCP expert who can tell us what could be the reason of this inconsistency .

Comment: We solved this issue by synchronizing browser timeout and server timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue by synchronizing browser timeout and server timeouts.

The fix was to make sure the TCP keepalive time and browser coincide or come at same time, causing the TCP connection to completely drop.